# How to open app from Recently open apps in android device using Appium?

Tags: automation, appium

I have tried the following code for the above mentioned problem,

```
    driver.pressKey(new KeyEvent().withKey(AndroidKey.APP_SWITCH));
    //Code for swipe left

    ((AndroidDriver) driver).startActivity(new Activity(ANDROID_PACKAGE, ANDROID_STARTACTIVITY));
    //user you application package name and activity for start application
```

When I switch between applications my previous application gets restart. Could anyone please help me to stop this restart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Key presses on appium are done by 
`driver.press_keycode(code)`

[All  required codes can be found here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html)

- 187 - KEYCODE_APP_SWITCH

So in your case, 
The final code would be like,

`driver.press_keycode(187)`  - KEYCODE_APP_SWITCH